# How to identify any weak MACs, Ciphers in the sshd_config

Tags: linux, ssh

I read this [article](https://www.virtuesecurity.com/kb/ssh-weak-mac-algorithms-enabled/), where it pointed out the weak mac algorithms. And currently I removed any bad Macs from my `sshd_configuration`. But I am still worried about the `Ciphers`.

Here's my `sshd_config` file. Can someone help me identify the weak `Ciphers` and `Macs` ?

```
...
Ciphers aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha1,,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1  
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download a system hardening guide (e.g. [this one](https://www.cisecurity.org/benchmark/red_hat_linux) from the CIS) and use that to check.

From the latest (2022-03-21) RHEL 7 benchmark:

```
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128- gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2- 512,hmac-sha2-256
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2- nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange- sha256
```